# Telegram bot api. Как сделать, чтобы бот отвечал на сообщения?

Tags: java, api, telegram, бот

Как сделать так, чтобы бот отвечал на сообщение пересылая его?

Я умею делать ответ без пересылки, но я хочу чтобы бот пересылал. Пример на скрине. На вики не могу найти внятное обьяснение.

[image: скриншот]

https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/wiki/Additional-Examples

Заранее спасибо.

---

**UPD.** Помогло использование параметра replyToMessageId, но только в переписке с ботом тет-а-тет. а в чатах он отвечает только на команды через слеш. а мне нужно чтобы он отвечал на сообщение без слеша. прикрепил еще один скриншот....

[image]

```
if (update.hasMessage() &&update.getMessage().hasText())  {
        String chatId = String.valueOf (update.getMessage().getChatId());
        SendMessage message = new SendMessage();
        message.enableMarkdown(true);
        message.setChatId(chatId);
        message.setReplyToMessageId(update.getMessage().getMessageId());
        try {
            String text = update.getMessage().getText();

            if (text.equals("тест")){
                message.setText("тест");
                execute(message);
```

Comment: Проверьте у метода отправки сообщения параметр replyToMessageId

Comment: это помогло, но только  в переписке с ботом тет-а-тет. а в чатах он отвечает только на команды через слеш. а мне нужно чтобы он отвечал на сообщение без слеша. прикрепил еще один скриншот....

Comment: Уточнения делайте в своем вопросе, не в ответе :) Уточнение перенес в вопрос, в следующий раз сделайте это сами ;) А ответ удалите

Comment: А обработчик-то для сообщений есть? Или у вас только для команд?

Comment: обработчик для сообщений есть. но в том-то и дело, что он запускается ТОЛЬКО когда перед сообщением поставить слеш.  а если ЛИЧНО боту писать, то на удивление слеш не нужен

Comment: `он запускается ТОЛЬКО когда перед сообщением поставить слеш` это не в личной переписке с ботом? Бот в группе вызывается или как встроенный bot?

Comment: ну, он состоит в чате

Comment: ВСЕ! Заработало, оказывается нужно было дать ему права администратора чтобы он получит доступ к сообщениям!

Comment: Молодец, что разобрались :) Оформите, пожалуйста, ответ с указанием решения, я вам +1 поставлю :)

Comment: готово . ответ оформлен:)

Comment: Спасибо, ответ хороший :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы бот отвечал в группах - нужно пригласить его в группу и выдать доступ к сообщениям

[image]

```
if (update.hasMessage() &&update.getMessage().hasText())  {
    String chatId = String.valueOf (update.getMessage().getChatId());
    SendMessage message = new SendMessage();
    message.enableMarkdown(true);
    message.setChatId(chatId);
    message.setReplyToMessageId(update.getMessage().getMessageId());
    try {
        String text = update.getMessage().getText();

        if (text.equals("тест")){
            message.setText("ответ");
            execute(message);
```